# Switching SetInterval to SetTimeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, memory-leaks, settimeout, setinterval

I'm currently using a SetInterval function along with an Ajax call to reload a partial view every 30 seconds, as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //reload new jobs every 30 sec
    setInterval(function () {
        //only reload the sections between certain times
        var date = new Date();
        var hour = date.getHours();

        if (hour >= 7 && hour <= 21) {
            ReloadNew();
        }
    }, 30000);

    function ReloadNew() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("NewFaults","Fault")",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#NewFaults').html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However i've been having memory leak issues and after a bit of researching I have found that using SetInterval with Ajax is not advised as they stack when the window is out of focus and then all run at once when it is back in focus. The advise is to use SetTimeout instead.

However from what i've seen there are multiple ways to implement a SetTimeout with an Ajax call, so I was wondering if someone could help me with how to adapt what I have above to use SetTimeout instead.

Thanks

Comment: SetTimeout only run one time instead of every time period.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but I suspect your leak could be from `$('#NewFaults').html(html);`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function ConsiderReload() {
        //only reload the sections between certain times
        var date = new Date();
        var hour = date.getHours();

        if (hour >= 7 && hour <= 21) {
            ReloadNew();
        }

        setTimeout(ConsiderReload, 30000);
    }

    function ReloadNew() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("NewFaults","Fault")",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#NewFaults').html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    ConsiderReload();
});
```